# AngularJs does not read url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, url

I need to use angularJS to call a rest api located at `localhost:80/users`.
The problem is that it does not read the url (the url works if I access it in the browser).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/welcome.htm").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code from above (which is from https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_services_http) on my PC I don't see the correct result. Instead

> Today's welcome message is:
>
> Hello AngularJS Students
>
> The $http service requests a page on the
>   server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome"
>   variable.

I see

> Today's welcome message is:
>
> The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is
>   set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.

in Chrome and Firefox.

If I replace the url from the code (https://www.w3schools.com/angular/welcome.htm) with my `localhost/users`, I also don't see the correct result. **But**, if the url is https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/region/europe it works! Why does it work for some URLs and it does not for others?

The server which is running the angularJs uses a different localhost port than the Rest server provider. Could this be the problem?

I use the latest AngularJS version (1.6.7).

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is;  You seem to be describing CORS issues, but without knowing what errors you are getting in the console, it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: The second quote block does not show the `Hello AngularJS Students` message, which should be read  fromhttps://www.w3schools.com/angular/welcome.htm .

Comment: Do you have any tips for CORS?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions and answers here on this site alone that deal with CORS, not to mention all the info other places on the net.  However, as I said, it's really hard to know for sure what the problem truly is, or offer possible fixes, without seeing the error messages you are getting.  CORS is only a guess due to the common symptoms you describe.

Comment: CORS is a server issue, not a client issue, and you haven't even described what server your API was built using.

Comment: If they are server issues, why does the code run normally on w3schools.com website and not so normally on my PC?

Comment: because the server allows requests from other pages that it hosts but not pages hosted elsewhere?

Comment: copying your code exactly as is into a plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/39gImG1ZBYIhsInB4DWq?p=preview shows exactly what I expected: `(index):1 Failed to load https://www.w3schools.com/angular/welcome.htm: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.`.  `https://www.w3schools.com` isn't a REST API URL, its an HTML document, which is not allowed to be transferred over ajax to outside domains. `$http` uses ajax, not http, despite it's name.